# How to reset password with UserManager of ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, passwords, asp.net-mvc-5, reset-password, usermanager

I am wondering if there is  a way to reset password with `UserManager` of **ASP.NET MVC 5**

I tried this with user that already has a password but no success. Any clue?

```
IdentityResult result = UserManager.AddPassword(forgotPasswordEvent.UserId.ToString(), model.ConfirmPassword);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
       //
}
else
{
        AddErrors(result);
}
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It is here [ASP.NET Identity reset password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524111/asp-net-identity-reset-password)

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = 
    new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

userManager.RemovePassword(userId);

userManager.AddPassword(userId, newPassword);
```

Comment: And what do you do if addpassword fails? now user has no password? there are better options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524111/asp-net-identity-reset-password

Comment: @mendel maybe transactionScope is possible solution :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you have the code in the standard `AccountController.cs`, you can just use the `UserManager` available there.

Comment: This site has a working example which includes handling results of the calls http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92737/asp-net-identity-admin-reset-user-password

Answer (score 31):

I suppose this is newer but there is such an API in Identity 2.0:

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
```

model.Code is generated the following way, and you should send this as a link in a email to make sure the user who is claiming to want to change the password is that one that owns the email address:

```
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

Comment: `UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id), model.Password);`

Comment: is the reset code saved in database ? How it check when we call resetpasswordasync method ?

Answer (score 8):

```
var validPass= await userManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(txtPassword1.Text);
if(validPass.Succeeded)
{
    var user = userManager.FindByName(currentUser.LoginName);
    user.PasswordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(txtPassword1.Text);
    var res= userManager.Update(user);
    if(res.Succeeded)
    {
        // change password has been succeeded
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try using the user store:

```
 var user = UserManager.FindById(forgotPasswordEvent.UserId);

 UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
 store.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, uManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.ConfirmPassword));
```

The IdentityMembership is cool, but still [lacking some implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466222/whys-delete-not-supported-in-asp-net-identity)

**UPDATE**

Identity 2.0 is here now and has a lot more features

Comment: I tried your sample but then I get a `TimeOutException`. I'm still using *Identity 1.0* and I don't think I can migrate as it would require major refactoring in my application. Am using *Microsoft.Owin 2.10* and *OWIN 1.0*

Answer (score 4):

Try this code .It is working perfectly:

```
    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();

    var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

    string userName= UserName.Text;

    var user =userManager.FindByName(userName);
    if (user.PasswordHash != null  )
    {
        userManager.RemovePassword(user.Id);
    }

    userManager.AddPassword(user.Id, newpassword);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order to make sure your answer is as helpful as possible to as broad an audience as possible, you might consider revising it to include (1) an evaluation of what was flawed about the existing code, (2) how your code avoids such pitfalls, and (3) any assumptions or shortcomings in your solution.  Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for inspiration.  Thanks again for posting an answer, and I hope to see more from you in the future.

Comment: how is this different from the current accepted answer?

Comment: the old answer does not tell how to get the userd and pass it as user.id like this:   string userName= UserName.Text;

    var user =userManager.FindByName(userName); it didn't check the condition if the password has null value .

Comment: @GaneshPMP: That's a valid reply. So incorporate that into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my UserManager class :

```
    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> UpdatePassword(ApplicationUser user, string newPassword)
    {
        var passwordStore = Store as IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser, string>;

        if (passwordStore == null)
            throw new Exception("UserManager store does not implement IUserPasswordStore");

        var result = await base.UpdatePassword(passwordStore, user, newPassword);

        if (result.Succeeded)
            result = await base.UpdateAsync(user);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what is you base class here?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, its UserManager<ApplicationUser>. ApplicationUser is derived from IdentityUser. The UserManager has a property "Store" that is (usually) an instance of IUserPasswordStore<YourUserClass,YourIdType>.

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured that out, but I don't see any `UpdatePassword` method, could you please tell me what version of Identity and OWIN are you using?

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />

Answer (score 2):

There are extension to change the password in the namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497466(v=vs.108).aspx